# How do I get past the following GTK4 build errors in Rust

Tags: rust

I have downloaded the GTK4 demo from Github and placed it in a directory.  I have opened it in VC and attempt to run the demo according to the Read.ME.  I get the following

```
PS D:\Rust\Projects\gtk4-rs-master\examples\basics> cargo run --bin basics
   Compiling pango-sys v0.16.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#bba02e39)
   Compiling cairo-sys-rs v0.16.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#bba02e39)
   Compiling graphene-sys v0.16.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#bba02e39)
   Compiling gdk4-sys v0.5.0 (D:\Rust\Projects\gtk4-rs-master\gdk4\sys)
   Compiling gsk4-sys v0.5.0 (D:\Rust\Projects\gtk4-rs-master\gsk4\sys)
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "cairo" "cairo >= 1.14"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1

error: failed to run custom build command for `cairo-sys-rs v0.16.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#bba02e39)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\Rust\Projects\gtk4-rs-master\target\debug\build\cairo-sys-rs-45e88069668b1029\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CAIRO_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:warning=`"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "cairo" "cairo >= 1.14"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1
  error: could not find system library 'cairo' required by the 'cairo-sys-rs' crate

  --- stderr
  Failed to open 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig\harfbuzz.pc': Too many open files
  Package 'harfbuzz', required by 'FreeType 2', not found

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "pango" "pango >= 1.46"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1

The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gtk4" "gtk4 >= 4.0.0"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1

error: build failed
PS D:\Rust\Projects\gtk4-rs-master\examples\basics>
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: did you install the required libraries?

Comment: This is suspicious: `Failed to open 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig\harfbuzz.pc': Too many open files` - maybe check your ulimits? Though if `harfbuzz.pc` is somehow ill-formed and causing an infinite loop that's opening files, that might not help. [It probably is](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/7399).

Comment: Very good question about the libraries.  I have set the enviro to point to the libraries and have checked they do exist in that directory.  I will see if I can find a copy of harfbuzz.pc and download a new copy.

Comment: Does anyone have a copy of harfbuzz.pc they can get to me?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be another application that used GTK was higher in the path than my Rust compilers entries were.  When I moved it down the application compiled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This question came up from the error message but was from a different cause for me. For me it was using Linuxbrew. I completely uninstalled it [https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20uninstall%20Homebrew,from%20the%20Homebrew%2Finstall%20repository](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#:%7E:text=How%20do%20I%20uninstall%20Homebrew,from%20the%20Homebrew%2Finstall%20repository).

Another user experienced a similar thing here https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/3856